# React Chart.js providing equal gap for xAxes showing formatted dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, charts, chart.js

After adding displayFormats in scales.x, now my xAxes labels are having different gaps according to the data object it contains. How do I make my xAxes labels to be shown with equal gaps?
The follow code is shown as follow image.
Please remember that I still need to use displayFormats to format my data.

[image]

```
  const levelHistoryOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 20,
        bottom: 20,
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      datalabels: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.main,
        anchor: "end",
        align: "top",
        font: {
          size: 16, // Adjust the font size as needed
        },
        formatter: (value, context) => {
          return context.chart.data.datasets[context.datasetIndex].data[
            context.dataIndex
          ];
        },
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "day",
          displayFormats: {
            day: "MM월 dd일",
          },
        },

        offset: true,
        ticks: {
          source: "data",
          font: {
            size: 16,
          },
          color: theme.palette.primary.main,
        },
        grid: {
          color: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#555" : "#ccc",
        },
        border: { color: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#555" : "#ccc" },
      },
      y: {
        offset: true,
        display: false,
        beginAtZero: false,
      },
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `x`-axis as `type: 'timeseries'` as shown below:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      ...
```

> For further information, please take a look at [Time Series Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/timeseries.html)
> in the `Chart.js` documentation.